# Error serializing JSON parsing - Decoding

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm having problems using swift 4 to decode and parse this JSON file data. I don't know how to structure my structs at the bottom of the code, so that they can cycle through my data of array dictionaries. ie. data[0], data[1], data[2] and so on.
This is the error I encounter:

*Error serializing JSON keyNotFound(whatsong.RecentTvList.(CodingKeys in _882383248D6F034EC588461F3FFE705E).title, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key title (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))*

```
{
data: [
    {
    _id: 100284,
    poster: "urlstring",
    title: "Happy!"
    },
    {
    _id: 100284,
    poster: "urlstring",
    title: "Happy!"
    }
    ]
}

let jsonUrlString = "HIDDEN"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
    {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {

            let show =  try
                JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvList.self, from: data)
            print(show)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()

struct RecentTvListData: Decodable  {
    var data: [RecentTvList]
}

struct RecentTvList: Decodable  {
    var title: String?
    var poster: String?
}
```

Comment: Show your`RecentTvList`  class or struct

Comment: I have, it's at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem I am seeing in your response is

`data: []`

Actually you are getting this dictionary  response

```
    {
    _id: 100284,
    poster: "urlstring",
    title: "Happy!"
    }
```

in to Array

And you are directly trying to pass response `Data` which contains Array of Dictionary  in  `RecentTvList` Which only accept  `Dictionary` That's why it is not able to identify key `title` as error Suggests

**EDIT**

Try to replace

```
let show =  try
            JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvList.self, from: data)
```

With

```
let show =  try
            JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)
```

Hope it is help to solve your issue

Comment: Ah shit!! So obvious, thanks so much mate. Fixed it like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    struct RecentTvList: Decodable  {
        var title: String
        var poster: String
        var _id : Int

    }
    struct RecentTvListData: Decodable  {
        var data: [RecentTvList]
    }
   let str =   """
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": 100284,
            "poster": "urlstring",
            "title": "Happy!"
        },
        {
            "_id": 100284,
            "poster": "urlstring",
            "title": "Happy!"
        }
    ]
}
"""
        do {
            let show =  try
                JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!)

            for tv in show.data  {
                print(tv._id)
            }
        } catch  {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Hmm not sure this helped. Are you able to please explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JSON you have supplied. There is no variable name `poster_url` in the response. This value should simply be `poster`.
In addition you have omitted the `-id` variable.

I think your JSON Structure should thus be:

```
struct RecentTvListData: Decodable  {
var data: [RecentTvList]

}

struct RecentTvList: Decodable  {
var _id : Int
var poster : String
var title : String

}
```

Comment: The data was just an example, sorry have fixed now. As I said, the error is to do with the json data structure.

Comment: No worries and yes the JSON was not formatted correctly, should be: {"data": [ { "_id": 100284, "poster": "urlstring", "title": "Happy!" }, {"_id": 100284, "poster": "urlstring", "title": "Happy!" }] }